# Filter on PropertyTypeAlias in Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a `Content Repository` which contains 2 sections, `Career Categories` and `Branches`.

I have create for each one a filter, below you can find the code for `Career categories`. This is working fine. Now I want to display the amount of visible content nodes for each item of the filter.

The content node contains 2 properties which are content pickers set to only select one.

Property alias for the `Career category` picker is `function`.

This doesn't work which give me always 0, but I have created one content page. What am I missing here?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Macros.PartialViewMacroPage

@*
    This snippet takes all of the career categories to create a filter
*@

@{

    // Take the content repository node
    IPublishedContent contentRepository = Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("ContentElements").FirstOrDefault();

    // Take the career categories node
    var careerCategorieRep = contentRepository.Children.Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"ucCareersCategoryRepository\"").FirstOrDefault();

    // Take the careers list content node
    IPublishedContent careersList = Umbraco.ContentAtRoot().DescendantsOrSelf("CareersList").FirstOrDefault();

}

<ul class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 aside-widget-container">
    <li class="widget">
        <div class="title">
            <h3>Beroep</h3>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
            @* // Loop over the categories *@
            @foreach (var careerCategorie in careerCategorieRep.Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("Name").ToList())
            {
                // Here I need to filter on the career category to get the amount of visible nodes in the content
                var count = careersList.Children.Where("Visible && function == " + careerCategorie.Id).Count();

                <li><a href="@careerCategorie.Id">@careerCategorie.Name<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is in this line of code:

```
var count = careersList.Children.Where("Visible && function == " + careerCategorie.Id).Count();
```

I need to get the amount of visible pages which has a certain property value, eg. content picker with Id of the career category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the solution:

I needed to surround the Id with quotes because its stored as a string and not as a int.

```
var count = careersList.Children.Where("Visible && function == \"" + careerCategorie.Id + "\"").Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should probably be using `TypedContentAtRoot` and not `ContentAtRoot`.  TypedContent is retrieved from the Umbraco.config xml cache  rather than the database so should be faster.

From your explanation I think you are saying that this line is the problem

```
var careerCategorieRep = contentRepository.Children.Where("DocumentTypeAlias == \"ucCareersCategoryRepository\"").FirstOrDefault();
```

Change it to

```
var contentRepository.Children.FirstOrDefault(n => n.DocumentTypeAlias == "ucCareersCategoryRepository");
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my other answer has some good advice but I think your problem may be  something else.

if you are searching for Visible nodes this relies on a property on your document type called `umbracoNaviHide`.  The property should be of a true/false datatype.

You have to add this property to the doc type and then set it to true (checked) if you wish to hide a node.

Then you can use either

```
myNode.Children.Where("Visible")
```

OR (just to show the way in which you can write lambda filter expressions)

```
myNode.Children.Where(x => x.IsVisible())
```

OR (this last just to illustrate that umbracoNaviHide is just a property on a doc type)

```
myNode.Children.Where(x => x.GetPropertyValue<string>("umbracoNaviHide")=="1")
```

Comment: No this is not the problem, view my update. It's filtering on a content picker property that is not working.